# Question about Bell's 1964 paper and its Illustration section

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality, epr-experiment

I have been trying to understand the maths behind the original paper on the EPR paradox, and I understand most of the details within it, in particular the main argument. However it is in the third section in equation 9 where i become a bit lost. The meaining marked equation seemes to escape me and I can't find much clarification on what it specifically denotes. From what I can tell result B is arranged to depend on both of the magnet oriantations a and b

$B = B(a, b)=-sign  \mathbf b  \mathbf\lambda$

[image]
But the lack of vector quotes above it throws me off. I can't see how it relates to ten (probably because im not sure what it implies).

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: A pdf copy of the paper is currently available from [this 2014 CERN webpage](https://home.cern/news/news/physics/fifty-years-bells-theorem).

Comment: In the book I have where that paper is reprinted there are  no vector quotes over any of $a,b$. It is obviously just a typo.